Issues in Data Anonymisation for a Big Data coursework/Assignment
I am trying to do data anonymization. The patient's data is getting anonymised. However, there seems to be still some issues in picking up few data. Can someone help me in finding the issue in my code?
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class AnonymizationApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String inputFile = "PatientNotes.txt";
        String outputFile = "AnonymizedReport.txt";

        try {
            String sampleNotes = readInputFile(inputFile);
            System.out.println("Replacing personal data with unique IDs: \n");
            System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
            String anonymizedNotes = anonymizeData(sampleNotes);
            writeOutputFile(anonymizedNotes, outputFile);
            System.out.println("\n\nAnonymized report saved as: " + outputFile);
            System.out.println("\n");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error reading/writing file: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static String readInputFile(String filename) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append("\n");
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void writeOutputFile(String text, String filename) throws IOException {
        try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(filename)) {
            writer.write(text);
        }
    }

    public static String anonymizeData(String text) {
        final String namePattern = "\\b(Ms\\.|Mr\\.|Mrs\\.|Dr\\.)(\\s[A-Z][a-z]+)(\\s[A-Z][A-Za-z]+)(?=,)";
        final String dobPattern = "\\d+-year-old|aged\\s\\d+";
        final String addressPattern = "(?<=\\bat\\s|\\bin\\s|\\bof\\s)(.*)?\\s(?:[A-Z][a-z]+\\s*)+,\\s[A-Z]{2}";

        Pattern nameRegex = Pattern.compile(namePattern);
        Pattern dobRegex = Pattern.compile(dobPattern);
        Pattern addressRegex = Pattern.compile(addressPattern);

        Map<String, String> nameIds = new HashMap<>();

        System.out.println("Anonymizing Titles, FirstNames, Lastnames (as .1): ");
        text = replacePersonalData(text, nameRegex, ".1", nameIds);

        System.out.println("\nAnonymizing Dates of Birth (as .2): ");
        text = replaceAges(text, dobRegex, ".2");

        System.out.println("\nAnonymizing Addresses With or Without Postal Codes (as .3): ");
        text = replaceAddresses(text, addressRegex, ".3");

        System.out.println("\nAnonymizing referenced Firstnames/Lastnames (as .4): ");
        text = replaceNames(text, nameIds);

        return text;
    }

    public static String replacePersonalData(String text, Pattern pattern, String suffix, Map<String, String> ids) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        int idCounter = 1;
        while (matcher.find()) {
            String match = matcher.group();
            String[] names = match.split("\\s+");

            if (names.length >= 2) {
                String title = names[0];
                String firstName = names[1];
                String lastName = names[names.length - 1];

                String fullFirstName = title + " " + firstName;
                String fullLastName = title + " " + lastName;

                if (!ids.containsKey(fullFirstName)) {
                    ids.put(fullFirstName, idCounter + ".4");
                }
                if (!ids.containsKey(fullLastName)) {
                    ids.put(fullLastName, idCounter + ".4");
                }

                if (!ids.containsKey(firstName)) {
                    ids.put(firstName, idCounter + ".4");
                }
                if (!ids.containsKey(lastName)) {
                    ids.put(lastName, idCounter + ".4");
                }

            }
            String anonymizedMatch = idCounter + suffix;
            text = text.replace(match, anonymizedMatch);
            System.out.println("Replaced: " + match + "  --------->>  " + anonymizedMatch);

            idCounter++;
        }
        return text;
    }

    public static String replaceAges(String text, Pattern pattern, String suffix) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        int idCounter = 1;
        while (matcher.find()) {
            String match = matcher.group();
            String anonymizedMatch = idCounter + suffix;
            text = text.replace(match, anonymizedMatch);
            System.out.println("Replaced: " + match + "  --------->>  " + anonymizedMatch);
            idCounter++;
        }
        return text;
    }

    public static String replaceAddresses(String text, Pattern pattern, String suffix) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        int idCounter = 1;
        while (matcher.find()) {
            String match = matcher.group();
            String anonymizedMatch = idCounter + suffix;
            text = text.replace(match, anonymizedMatch);
            System.out.println("Replaced: " + match + "  --------->>  " + anonymizedMatch);
            idCounter++;
        }
        return text;
    }

    public static String replaceNames(String text, Map<String, String> ids) {
        List<String> withTitle = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> withoutTitle = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String name : ids.keySet()) {
            if (name.contains("Mr.") || name.contains("Dr.") || name.contains("Ms.") || name.contains("Mrs.")) {
                withTitle.add(name);
            } else {
                withoutTitle.add(name);
            }
        }

        List<String> replacements = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String name : withTitle) {
            String replacement = text.replaceAll("\\b" + name + "\\b", ids.get(name));
            if (!replacement.equals(text)) {
                replacements.add("Replaced: " + name + " -------->> " + ids.get(name));
                text = replacement;
            }
        }

        for (String name : withoutTitle) {
            String replacement = text.replaceAll("\\b" + name + "\\b", ids.get(name));
            if (!replacement.equals(text)) {
                replacements.add("Replaced: " + name + " -------->> " + ids.get(name));
                text = replacement;
            }
        }

        for (String replacement : replacements) {
            System.out.println(replacement);
        }

        return text;
    }
}

I was required to write a JAVA program to anonymise patient record data file using regular
expressions in Java. Sample data of patient records are available on the module Moodle page.
Patient's names, titles, dates of birth, and addresses must be anonymised and replaced with ID
numbers. The ID numbers must be mapped to the patient's name, title, date of birth, and address
in a separate document. For example,
Sample Medical Notes:
During the consultation, Mr. Alex Max, (DOB: 11-03-1965) a gentleman residing at 55 Regex
Lane, Liverpool, UK, presented with mild chest pain and occasional shortness of breath during
exertion. He has a history of hypertension managed with amlodipine (5mg) daily since 2008.
No cardiac abnormalities or major surgeries were reported. Mr. Max has a 20-year history of
smoking and occasional alcohol consumption within recommended limits. Family history
reveals hypertension and cardiovascular diseases, including myocardial infarction in his
paternal grandfather. Further evaluation including ECG and cardiac stress test is advised to
assess his symptoms. Recommendations include smoking cessation, lifestyle modifications,
and a follow-up appointment in two weeks for review and adjustment of the treatment plan.
Your application output must be as following:
Anonymised Medical Notes
During the consultation, 1.1, (DOB: 1.2) a gentleman residing at 1.3, presented with mild chest
pain and occasional shortness of breath during exertion. He has a history of hypertension
managed with amlodipine (5mg) daily since 2008. No cardiac abnormalities or major surgeries
were reported. 1.4 has a 20-year history of smoking and occasional alcohol consumption within
recommended limits. Family history reveals hypertension and cardiovascular diseases,
including myocardial infarction in his paternal grandfather. Further evaluation including ECG
and cardiac stress test is advised to assess his symptoms. Recommendations include smoking
cessation, lifestyle modifications, and a follow-up appointment in two weeks for review and
adjustment of the treatment plan.
COMM017 Big Data and Cloud Computing
V1.0 – 10-Mar-2024 Page 3 of 5
Mapping Document
1.1 Mr. Alex Max
1.2 11-03-1965
1.3 55 Regex Lane, Liverpool, UK
1.4 Mr. Max

